Mysql procedure executes multiple time
I have a MySQL procedure to export some content from a table. When I wrote it it worked perfectly but now when I want to re-execute it, it runs more than once.
Here is my procedure:
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE count_null(IN tbl_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE col_type VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT column_name, data_type
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = tbl_name; -- Use a different name for parameter
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO col_name, col_type;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @where_clause = '';
        IF col_type = 'date' THEN
            SET @where_clause = CONCAT(col_name, ' IS NULL');
        ELSE
            SET @where_clause = CONCAT(col_name, ' IS NULL OR ', col_name, ' = ""');
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', QUOTE(col_name), ' AS column_name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM ', tbl_name, ' WHERE ', @where_clause, ';');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END//

DELIMITER ;

and I run it with:
CALL count_null('TABLENAME');

the output of that is something like this:
+--------------+-------+
| column_name  | count |
+--------------+-------+
| baltimore_id |     0 |
+--------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| column_name   | count |
+---------------+-------+
| molecule_type |     0 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------+-------+
| column_name  | count |
+--------------+-------+
| baltimore_id |     0 |
+--------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| column_name   | count |
+---------------+-------+
| molecule_type |     0 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------+-------+
| column_name  | count |
+--------------+-------+
| baltimore_id |     0 |
+--------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| column_name   | count |
+---------------+-------+
| molecule_type |     0 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Also, the log of the workbench shows the procedure executes multiple times.
How to fix/prevent that?
(ps. For those who did not read the question well, I know the output and it is fine! only need to limit the procedure execution to one cycle.)

I know where the column data are coming from! I want to stop multiple running of that when I execute it only once.

MySQL Workbench should not run your query multiple times. You may have remaining statements in your query window and just run them when you run everything. Try opening an new, clean query window and run it from there.

Thanks, @Solarflare, I closed everything, even though I restarted the engine and recreated the procedure but still the same. As I mentioned, even if I execute it in MySQL prompt, with bash script or even workbench has the same wrong output. I am completely confused with that.

Do you maybe have the table in several databases? (Your query doesn't filter for the current database. Try running the cursor-query SELECT column_name, data_type... and check if it returns your columns multiple times.)

@solarflare OP already dismissed this  possibility..

The table is empty and if I do select there is no output from it. That is not relevant to the problem because the procedure has a counting task. That means with or without the presence of the content should work. To make it even more clear here is the list of the fields in Baltimore table:
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| baltimore_id  | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| molecule_type | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
I removed the extra lines for shortening

To give you a better idea, I installed another MySQL service on another VM, and with the test table, I have the same issue. I cant understand

I meant: do you have multiple copies of your database/schema (not how many rows are in the actual table)? E.g. if the table is in multiple database, the query on the information_schema will return a row for each table of the same name, so try running the query SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'TABLENAME' (with your tablename) and check if it returns 2 or 6 rows.

@Solarflare No I have a single database with such a table name. The output of that is also are 2 columns.
I believe my code has an issue, I created another procedure for a different purpose and it is executed once.

@Solarflare I added 'SELECT SLEEP(5);' for sleep 5 seconds in each turn of the loop and the output delayed between the repeats. But there is a confusing point that I have 2 fields in this table, why it repeats 3 times

It seems to work as intended here - db<>fiddle. It must be something about your environment.

@user1191247 thanks for the effort. How can I make sure this is running once? Because the output of the procedure (even after multiple times of execution) in the workbench is only one. But the log (action output) shows that.

Without understanding what is going on in your environment, I don't think there is anything else we can suggest. As the fiddle shows, the SPROC appears to function as intended. There is nothing in your question that explains the multiple executions of your SPROC. Checking that there is a currently selected database and adding AND table_schema = DATABASE() to the info schema query will make the SPROC more predictable, but obvs has no bearing on your multiple execution issue.

Finally, I found it. It was not due to env variables. I switched to the older version [MySQL 8.0.204] from [MySQL 8.0.36] and it is working now. I don't know what is the differences between these two but it is fine now.
